# Mobx does not rerender after an item in observable array has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I can not get the truth why the `TableContainer|TableComponent` component does not update its children properly.In a store i have an array of objects,when i am trying to update object property the `Table` does not update its values.If i replace whole array it is working though.

You can check this behaviour in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/400yw6yj2w).

Documentation states that initiating observable array,makes items observable too.([docs](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html#observable-arrays))

> Similar to objects, arrays can be made observable using
>   observable.array(values?) or by passing an array to observable. This
>   works recursively as well, so all (future) **values of the array will
>   also be observable.**

Why is this happening?i am coming from redux background and i am trying to wrap my head around mobx with no much of success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your FlipScrollTable component should be an `observer` as well

Comment: Thanks that would do it but that is quite strange, i would like to have this "dumb" component to stay dumb.Is there any other solution to this?correct me if i am wrong but presentational components should not have such logic.The presentational component should not be responsible for this.This solution breaks the [smart&dumb components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) pattern.Should this pattern apply to mobx?

Comment: If you want to benefit from observable data being observable, you have to use observers. Otherwise you should not be passing observable data into the 'dumb' component, but plain data instead. It is like passing an RXJS stream in, but never subscribing.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to dig into the mobx a little bit more.Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your injection directly to the TableComponent, for a stateless solution:

```
@inject("store")
@observer
class FlipScrollTable extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    var { columns, header } = this.props;
    var { array } = this.props.store;
    const classes = {};
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {columns.map((column, i) => {
              var { header, headerStyle } = column;
              return (
                <th key={i} style={headerStyle}>
                  {header}
                </th>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {array.map(row => {
            var tableCells = columns.map(column => {
              var { accessor, id, Value } = column;
              var value = _isFunction(accessor)
                ? accessor(row)
                : _get(row, accessor);

              var renderedValue = normalizeComponent(
                Value,
                { value, row },
                value
              );

              return (
                <td key={_isFunction(accessor) ? id : accessor}>
                  {renderedValue}
                </td>
              );
            });
            return <tr key={row.id}>{tableCells}</tr>;
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

With reference with your sandbox, it appears that you are attempting to change a component after it has been rendered; where you should re-render components directly from the observable array changes.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Mullings.The @mwestrate provided same solution but this somewhat breaks [smart&dumb](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) components pattern.Anyway the column `Value` renderer is wrapped in the Observer component.Cheers!

Comment: Try to imagine each component is an image! It can only be created by the information/ data injected into it. If you continue envisioning component as / like <divs> you'll only serve to limit your scope of functionality. This might help to expand upon what I'm referring to: https://github.com/jmullings/react101